# Expected running time of Clique on uniform graph

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Problem:

Input is (G, k) where

```
k is chosen uniformly from [1..n]
G is chosen by, for each edge, flipping an independent coin, and adding the edge to G w/ prob 1/2
```

Question: Does G have a clique of size k?

We want to solve this in expected time n^{2 log n}.

What I currently know:

There are papers from 1976 proving that the expected size of the clique in a random graph (as described above) is approximately log n).

For k < 2 log n, I can just brute force the entire graph in n^{2 log n} time.

Also, by the union bound, the probability of having a clique bigger than 2 log n is ~ (e / k )^{log n}.

However, I need to push that probability down to something that looks like 2^{-n^2} (the time required to brute force the entire graph.)

Questions:

1) Should I go read the Bollobas /Erdos (Cliques in random graphs), or is there an elementary way to prove this without citing their theorems?

2) If there ia an elementary way; what is it?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems $(e/k)^{\log n}$ is a really bad probability bound for the probability that a clique of size $k$ exists, and if you improved it, the result you want might be easy. For example, if you substitute k=n in there, your probability grows like $\exp(\log^2 n)$ whereas the real answer is $2^{-{n \choose 2}}$. Even for smaller $k$, I believe your bound is radically different from the correct answer. The first thing to try is to get the right bound.